# When to call UpdateLayeredWindow?

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface

I used UpdateLayeredWindow to draw a window which use png as background. But this window contain some self-draw buttons which would change when user hover/click these buttons and then the window should change.

Now the problem is when should I call UpdateLayeredWindow. Shoud I call UpdateLayeredWindow after the user changed the button apperance, that is when user hover the mouse above the buttons or clicked the buttons?

Comment: I don't understand what redrawing the buttons placed on top of the background has to do with redrawing the background. You can do one without the other. There's no need to call `UpdateLayeredWindow` just because you change the button's appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When need to update the layeredwindow, call UpdateLayeredWindow, but be really careful with this.

Call it too frequently do cause performance problem, its not WM_PAINT which could combine to one if there is too much in the message queue. UpdateLayeredWindow do not...